# Node.JS os.cpus() Reports Wrong CPU Speed on M2 MacBook Air

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, macos

When I run `os.cpus()` in node terminal, the returned speed of cpu is `24` which is obviously incorrect. I only met the problem on this exact machine and my other Linux server returns correct numbers, so not really a big deal but very confusing.

My spec is `M2 MacBook Air 14"` on `macOS Sonoma 14.0` and Node.js `18.12.1`

Here is the output

```json
> os.cpus()
[
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: {
      user: 210292710,
      nice: 0,
      sys: 106153270,
      idle: 522189360,
      irq: 0
    }
  },
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: {
      user: 203549830,
      nice: 0,
      sys: 98067280,
      idle: 537528550,
      irq: 0
    }
  },
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: {
      user: 191730910,
      nice: 0,
      sys: 90061980,
      idle: 558158070,
      irq: 0
    }
  },
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: {
      user: 179903140,
      nice: 0,
      sys: 82694840,
      idle: 578338150,
      irq: 0
    }
  },
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: {
      user: 133762480,
      nice: 0,
      sys: 27584400,
      idle: 682604710,
      irq: 0
    }
  },
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: {
      user: 113063530,
      nice: 0,
      sys: 19108920,
      idle: 712395620,
      irq: 0
    }
  },
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: { user: 55913160, nice: 0, sys: 11789060, idle: 777338670, irq: 0 }
  },
  {
    model: 'Apple M2',
    speed: 24,
    times: { user: 43927240, nice: 0, sys: 10205050, idle: 791226910, irq: 0 }
  }
]
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in older Node.js versions. I can reproduce this error with the Node.js version you mentioned, 18.12.1, but with the laters Node.js 21 I get a speed of 2400 on my machine, which makes more sense.